# RXJS error handling: Why is the handling different?

Tags: rxjs

The following stream doesn't complete when fetchData() throws an error, therefore the stream will never stop

```
timer(0, 5000)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      fetchData().pipe(
        catchError((err: any) => {
          // don't finalize the observable by throwing an error here, instead return a empty array
          return of([]);
        })
      )
    ),
    finalize(() => console.log('finish!'))
  );
```

But initally I thought the following stream would result in the same handling, but it doesn't.

```
timer(0, 5000)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    catchError((err: any) => {
      // don't finalize the observable by throwing an error here, instead return a empty array
      return of([]);
    }),
    finalize(() => console.log('finish!'))
  );
```

The difference here is, that in the first example the catchError is directly in the pipe of the fetchData().
In the second example the catchError is the next step after the switchMap.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xdzwhb?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Can somebody explain why it isn't the same?

Answer (score 1):

It's about the values in the timer pipe itself,
in the first example, fetchData pipe is returning an observable of an empty Array, and also will be the return value of the switchMap of the timer pipe, which means: for the timer, there's no Error detected, and no reason to stop!

In the second example, the error is directly returned in the timer pipe,  which leads to stopping the timer and triggering the timer's catchError itself, then calling the timer's finalize

Answer (score 1):

The difference has to do with the `switchMap`’s “inner observable”. In the first case the inner observable handles the error, so the switchMap itself never emits an error.

If an error is never emitted, the next time switchMap receives a value from `timer`, it will keep working.

In the second case, the error does reach the `switchMap`, so it will emit the error and complete, thus not processing any further values.